# Making the copy paste process run faster

Tags: performance, excel, copy-paste, vba

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = ActiveWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("S:\HR\Attendance Charts\2014\May 14\abc.xlsx")

y.Sheets("Report").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A34:DM64").Copy

x.Sheets("Modified").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A70").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

y.Close
End Sub
```

I am using this code to copy some data from x workbook to y workbook. Size of x workbook is 13 MB and the Y is 23.5 MB. Copying the data from x and pasting it to y takes a lot of time. Is there anyway I can make this process run faster? I am using the code above. Thanks

Comment: Set calculation to manual before you copy/paste, then turn it on again after the copy is complete? It might help.

Comment: I made the calculations manual, but there is no noticeable change in the performance.

Comment: in fact it copies from y to x, and not like you said, i had a lot of confusion because of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm , the following may make your code faster (it bypasses the clipboard and copies the values directly):

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim r1 As Range ' source
Dim r2 As Range ' destination

Set x = ActiveWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks.Open("S:\HR\Attendance Charts\2014\May 14\abc.xlsx")

Set r1 = y.Sheets("Report").Range("A34:DM64")
Set r2 = x.Sheets("Modified").Range("A70:DM100") 
r2.Value = r1.Value '<<<<<<<<< this is the line that does the magic

y.Close

End Sub
```

*Do* check that I set the ranges `r1` and `r2` correctly...

Comment: @Ashonna glad to hear it. I didn't actually know this trick - all I can claim is to have good Google skills. Adding it to my own repertory now!

Answer (score 0):

i changed Floris's code a bit, to try with a VBA Array

```
Sub test()

with Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    .enableevents=false
    .calculation = Xlmanual
end with

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim r1 As Range ' source
Dim r2 As Range ' destination
Dim Y_Array() as Variant
dim Y_Sheet as Worksheet
Dim X_Sheet as Worksheet

Set x = ActiveWorkbook
Set X_Sheet= x.Sheets("Modified") '=activesheet ' i've preferably named it with complete name here

'testing if y already opened, if it's the case win a lot of time
err.clear
on error resume next
Set y = Workbooks ("abc.xlsx")
if err<>0 then
    err.clear
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("S:\HR\Attendance Charts\2014\May 14\abc.xlsx")
end if
on error goto 0

with y
    application.windows(.name).windowstate=xlminimized
    set Y_Sheet= .Sheets("Report")
    with Y_Sheet
        Set r1 = .Range(.cells(34,1) , .cells(64,117) ) ' same as "A34:DM64")
        with r1
            redim Y_Array (1 to 30, 1 to 117) 'to make it a dynamic array : (1 to .rows.count, 1 to .columns.count)
            Y_Array = .value2 'edit : modified to .value2
        end with
    end with
end with

Set r2 = x.Sheets("Modified").Range("A70:DM100") 

r2.Value2 = Y_Array 'r1.Value '<<<<<<<<< this is the line that does the magic 'edit: modified to value2

y.Close

'Free memory
erase Y_Array
set r1=nothing
set Y_Sheet=nothing
set Y=nothing
set r2=nothing
set X_Sheet=nothing
set X=nothing

with Application
    .ScreenUpdating = true 'uh, without reseting it to normal you gonna have troubles....
    .DisplayAlerts = true
    '.AskToUpdateLinks = true
    .enableevents = true
    .calculation = XlAutomatic
end with

End Sub
```

Code untested, not sure it really helps, give it a try...

Comment: i rencently learned that .value2 is faster than .value, exept it wont handle currency and date types. i ajusted the code